# Run into "QuerySyntaxException: *** is not mapped" when upgrading spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-orm

The application works previously.

When we upgrade spring boot from 2.3.4.RELEASE to 2.5.14, the application run into this exception: QuerySyntaxException: *** is not mapped.

I can't tell whether all entities would but I've seen multiple entities failing with this exception.
Here's an  example:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ModelSummary is not mapped [from ModelSummary where :currentTime - lastUpda
teTime <= :timeFrame]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:734) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor138.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
.......................................
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ModelSummary is not mapped [from ModelSummary where :currentTime - lastUpdateTime <= :timeFrame]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:613) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        ... 160 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ModelSummary is not mapped
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:333) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3765) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3654) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:737) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:593) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:613) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.jar:5.4.33]
        ... 160 more
```

btw, I don't find the source code of org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper in https://github.com/hibernate/, I believe it'll help if someone could point me to it.

Comment: Ok, I got SessionFactoryHelper, it gets removed in latest main, but existed in tag 5.4.33

Comment: I think this is more likely related to spring-boot or spring-data-jpa, as I've tested it worked in the combination of spring-boot 2.3.4.RELEASE and hibernate-core 5.6.14.final (yes I also tried this version besides 5.4.33)

Comment: The cause is, when working with spring-boot 2.5.14, org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findEntityPersisterByName return null, and there's only 2 entities in sfi.getMetamodel().entityPersisters().

However, when working with spring-boot 2.3.4.RELEASE, there's 259 entities inside, that's exactly the number we have.

Though there's no obvious difference between these two and all other entities, I'm still trying to find out it.

At the same time, could someone give me hints about this finding and how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I want to put this as an answer as this could free someone let him/her go ahead if he/she runs into the same situation.

We're using org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean to scan entities, tens of beans of this type are defined.

It happened that one of these beans set `primary="true"`, which is responsible for scanning two packages.

```
    <bean id="luckybean" 
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
            primary="true">
```

The result is only entities in these two packages get registered into `sfi.getMetamodel().entityPersisters()` in `SessionFactoryHelper`, as I mentioned in one of my comments.

All other entities are ignored, `QuerySyntaxException: *** is not mapped` throws when you access these ignored entities.

The issue gets fixed once removing `primary="true"`.

But I think this is not the final answer. What happened between spring-boot 2.3.4.RELEASE and 2.5.14, which cause the `primary` attribute of bean behaving differently?

I add spring-orm tag, see if someone from whatever spring team could give hints. I myself will dig more too.

Comment: This approach could solve the `QuerySyntaxException: *** is not mapped` issue. But without `primary="true"`, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer will throw exeception with message "required a single bean, but 2 were found", one bean is the entity manager factory, another is the session factory. How to fix this, can we specify a @Qualifier for this case, how?